# IntelliSense неправильно отображает ошибки

Tags: c#, wpf, intellisense

После неудачной перезагрузки компа Blend начал показывать, что не может найти элементы из xaml в cs коде. При сборке и запуске все работает, но показывает, будто программа вся в ошибках.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Закройте IDE, удалите папку `bin` и `obj`, также можете удалить временную папку `.vs` (скрыта) и файл `.user`, после чего откройте проект и пересоберите его (XAML генерируется только после **успешной** сборки проекта, если у проекта!). И да, советую познать MVVM и привязки.